# React Redux action payload data undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to set up authentication for my app. Data is returned by axios and action payload is called correctly. The problem comes when I try to access the data contained in the payload. It returns undefined.

Sign in component with redux-form:

```
class Signin extends Component {
  submit = values => {
    this.props.signInAction(values, this.props.history);
  };

  errorMessage() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
      return <div className="info-red">{this.props.errorMessage}</div>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit)} className="formu">
        <div>
          <div className="inputf">
            <Field
              name="login"
              component="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="inputf">
            <Field
              name="password"
              component="input"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className="bsignin" type="submit">
            Sign in
          </button>
          {this.errorMessage()}
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { errorMessage: state.auth.error };
}

const reduxFormSignin = reduxForm({
  form: "signin"
})(Signin);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { signInAction }
)(reduxFormSignin);
```

Action creator

```
export function signInAction({ login, password }, history) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await HTTP.post(`authenticate`, {
        login,
        password
      });
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
      const req = await HTTP.get("account");
      dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATED,
        payload: req.data
      });
      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR,
        payload: "Invalid userName or password"
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Reducer

```
import {
  AUTHENTICATED,
  UNAUTHENTICATED,
  AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
} from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  login: "",
  authority: ""
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTHENTICATED:
      //This console log works and returns the data
      console.log(action.payload);
      //Next console log returns payload is undefined
      //console.log(action.payload.login);
      return {
        ...state,
        authenticated: true,
        // login: action.payload.login,
        // authority: action.payload.authority
      };
    case UNAUTHENTICATED:
      return { ...state, authenticated: false };
    case AUTHENTICATION_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I'd like to set login and authority with the data comming from the payload but can't access the data inside it. ¿What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux Form has an onSubmit function which takes in an action directly 
https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/remotesubmit/

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="formu">
```

Then wrap within Redux Form

```
  const reduxFormSignin = reduxForm({
  form: "signin",
  onSubmit: signInAction
})(Signin);
```

Check within the Redux Debugger, you should see redux form recording data
Also remember to pass form reducer to your store as stated here https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...your other reducers here
  // you have to pass formReducer under 'form' key,
  // for custom keys look up the docs for 'getFormState'
  form: formReducer`enter code here`
})
```

Comment: The issue I'm having has nothing to do with the data from the form but the data coming from the axios request from /account. I receive the token and get the data from the account, but I can't assign it to the state on the reducer.

Comment: ok try something like this 
`let payload = action.payload;
  let data = { data: payload, errors: {} };

   return {
        ...state,
        ...data,
         authenticated: true
    }`

This way data can be available within the state and you can retrieve this data via props to perform any action

Comment: Ok that kinda worked. The problem now is that when I change routes the attribute "authenticated" persists but not the data. ¿How can I make data persist? Thanks for your answers, they are very usefull for a react begginer.

Comment: sounds like something `mapStateToProps` can help you achieve or you can call the AUTHENTICATED method again if you need data, that way you can pass `data` into initialState on the new route

Comment: I was calling the AUTHENTICATED method from the router with no data. Thanks a lot, you've been very helpfull.